# Storing string in database in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string

My String in php  is like 
0:12,1:123,2:234 .... n times

I want to store it in database as -->

```
0:12 --- 0 as room_number 12 as value
1:12 --- 1 as room_number 12 as value
```

databse structure is like --

```
id(primary) room_number value
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you come across PHP's explode() function?

Comment: @MarkBaker yes i explode it but not get desired result .

Comment: Can you post the code where you put it into the database?

Comment: First `explode(',',$string)` then explde each array key of resulting array like this: `explode(':',$result)`

Comment: So what are you getting from explode? It should be creating an array of values like "0:12", "1:123", "2:234", etc; which can then be split further into room number and value

Comment: @user2001057 - if you've tried something and it hasn't worked, you should show us what you've tried; you might be really close to getting the answer yourself, but we can't tell from the question. If we don't know how far you've got we have to give much more detailed answers, which means people are less likely to want to help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = '0:12,1:123,2:234';

$elements = explode(',', $string);

foreach($elements as $value){

        $value = explode(':', $value);
        echo 'Room: '.$value[0].', Value: '.$value[1].'<br/>';

        // Write some code here to insert into your database.
}
```

Comment: @user2001057 Upvote and Accept if it's the correct answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's `explode()` function to split by commas to get a string for each room, then `explode()` each one of the room strings by colon to get the individual values you're after. Now you've got the values, you should be able to use the normal DB handling functions to save the records.

Or to do it directly in the database without needing any PHP code (assuming you're using MySQL), you could use MySQL's `LOAD DATA INFILE` command, specifying a comma as the record terminator and colon as the field terminator.